# When creating a Nearest Neighbour from xyz, the raster cells are not centered with the original point cloud (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, point, interpolation, xyz

I have a gridded point cloud 0,25x025. I ran a Nearest Neighbour with the same resultion (cell 0,25). The points of the cloud and the raster are not centered as seen in the picutre. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: There are several tools in QGIS called 'nearest neighbor' - which one are you using?

Comment: I don't see any points.

Comment: Sagas NN. The points are yellow and in the left corner of the cells.